# Auf der Straße oder auf die Straße?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case, wechselpraeposition

Was ist richtig auf Deutsch?

> Wir fahren mit dem Auto auf **die** Straße.
> Wir fahren mit dem Auto auf **der** Straße.

Benutzt man hier Akkusativ oder Dativ?

Comment: Vielen Dank für Ihre Antwort, Herr Schölnast! Jetzt verstehe ich den Unterschied.

Answer (score 3):

Es kann beides richtig sein. *... auf die Straße* bedeutet: Das Auto ist woanders, z. B. auf einer Wiese, und fährt dann auf die Straße. Es wird also eine Richtung angegeben. *... auf der Straße* bedeutet, das Auto fährt, und es wird angegeben, wo es fährt, also den Ort.

Comment: Auf die = onto (or into). auf der = on

Comment: @planetmaker, da die Frage auf Deutsch gestellt. Es ergibt wenig Sinn, Vergleiche mit einer anderen Sprache herzustellen, wenn wir gar nicht wissen, ob der Fragensteller oder die Fragenstellerin sie überhaupt beherrscht.

Comment: Ich danke Ihnen für die Erklärung, Herr Peters. Ja, ich habe eigentlich auch so gedacht, wie Sie und oben Herr Schölnast geschrieben haben, aber in der Übung im Lehrbuch war nur eine Antwort möglich). Deshalb wollte ich klären, vielleicht denkt man in der deutschen Sprache anders) in diesem Fall.

Comment: @Maryna Gerne geschehen! Manchmal gibt es Fehler in den Büchern.

Answer (score 1):

Das Wort *auf* ist eine Wechselpräposition:

- *»auf«* + Richtung oder Ziel einer Bewegung = Akkusativ

  > Ich gehe auf **die** Straße.

  Die Straße ist das Ziel, auf das ich mich hin bewege.

  Das bedeutet: Ich bin jetzt nicht auf der Straße, sondern im Wald, auf einer Wiese oder in einem Haus. Und dann gehe ich, und diese Bewegung führt mich von meinem aktuellen Aufenthaltsort (Wald, Wiese, Haus) fort. Wenn die Bewegung zu Ende ist, werde ich mich auf der Straße befinden.
- *»auf«* + Ort der Handlung = Dativ

  > Ich gehe auf **der** Straße.

  Die Straße ist der Ort an dem ich die Bewegung ausführe.

  Das bedeutet: Ich befinde mich bereits auf der Straße. Dort gehe ich. Während ich diese Bewegung mache, bleibe ich aber die ganze Zeit wo ich schon von Beginn an war: Ich bleibe auf der Straße. Ich bewege mich zwar auf der Straße weiter, aber ich verlasse die Straße nicht, und ich muss sie auch nicht betreten, weil ich ja ohnehin von Anfang auf der Straße bin.

---

**Off topic, passt aber irgendwie doch dazu:**

Diese Unterscheidung von Richtung/Ziel und Ort der Handlung ist etwas, das ganz grundlegend in der deutschen Sprache ist. Es ist so grundlegend, dass es sogar die Wahrnehmung von deutschen Muttersprachlern beeinflusst:

Man hat englischen und deutschen Muttersprachlern ein Foto gezeigt, auf dem zwei Frauen zu sehen sind, die von der Kamera weggehen. Die Frauen gehen auf einem schmalen Gehweg, der nach wenigen Metern an einer kurzen Treppe endet, die nach oben führt. Die Probanden wurden gebeten, das Bild mit wenigen Worten zu beschreiben.

- Die große Mehrheit der englischen Muttersprachler sagte (natürlich auf Englisch): *»Zwei Frauen gehen einen Weg entlang.«*
- Die deutschen Muttersprachler sagten aber fast alle: *»Zwei Frauen gehen auf eine Treppe zu.«*

Als die Probanden später gefragt wurden, was sich am Ende des Weges befand, konnten fast alle deutschen Muttersprachler sagen, dass es eine kurze Treppe war. Von den englischen Muttersprachlern konnten sich signifikant weniger Personen an die Treppe erinnern.

Das wir von Experten darauf zurückgeführt, dass Richtungen und Ziele von Bewegungen im Deutschen sehr viel wichtiger sind als im Englischen.

Comment: +1. Aber hast Du für diese jetzt schon häufiger in diesem SE gelesenen anekdotische Unterscheidung zwischen Ort/Richtung und der Wahrnehmung der entsprechenden Muttersprachler eine Quelle zur Hand? Mir deucht, dass es in dieser Vereinfachung schon soweit gehen könnte, dass der Inhalt der Studie möglicherweise nicht mehr richtig widergegeben wird.

Comment: @planetmaker Ich habe das aus diesem Video erfahren: https://youtu.be/iwzYCbNT4BA?t=520 (ab ca. 8:40) In der Video-Beschreibung ist zwar eine Studie verlinkt, darin geht es aber um die Wahrnehmung des Zeitflusses bei australischen Ureinwohnern. Man müsste den Urheber des Videos nach seiner Quelle fragen.